# Custom email for Woocommerce (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I created custom HTML template with inline styles for 'customer processing order' email notification in Woocommerce (woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-processing-order.php) and put it in my themes folder.

However, I am stuck in this section:

```
<tbody>
    <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( $order->is_download_permitted(), true, $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ); ?>
</tbody>
```

this echo outputs the table with data and i cannot understand where to add styles.

Please, advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at `woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-item.php`; that's the template that outputs the table rows. As per the other template, copy it to your theme folder and then you can customise it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [the documentation for template overrides here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/). As Dre pointed out earlier as well, `woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-item.php` can help you with this. Be sure to point them in the right directory within your theme per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**How to style WooCommerce Emails**

The template email folder `woocommerce/templates/emails/` (original plugin folder not your child theme) has a file called `email-styles.php`. You will find all styles there to override or add new ones.

In that regard I'd also suggest the plugin WooCommerce E-Mail Preview, which gives you an HTML view of the email, so you can inspect and target elements for styling.